# Action Elements in a draggable view using UIPanGestureRecognizer causes the view to shift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, uipangesturerecognizer

I wanted to create a draggable view which has many action elements. To accomplish this I replicated the code through Apple Documentation for creating a draggable view from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

The view gets panned as expected but when an action element is clicked the view shifts to some other location. Here is the sample code and a screenshot of Main.storyboard to replicate the issue.

[image: Main.storyboard]

ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)segmentedAction:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

And this is the code in the ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];
        
        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}
- (IBAction)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];
    
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
        
        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}
- (IBAction)segmentedAction:(id)sender {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",self.segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
@end
```

Can anybody guide me as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to move a group of controls on pan gesture? And to which view is the pan gesture added?

Comment: the pan gesture is added to the view containing the segmented control and the label, and yes i want to move the view and all the elements contained in it

Comment: This behavior is not because of touching on the action item, but happens when you set the text on label.  Commenting the line "self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",self.segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex];" will fix the issue. But I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally got the problem. This is happening because of the Autolayout. When you try to set the text of the label, the autolayout is forcing the view frame to reset to the initial values. Since you have changed the anchorpoint, it will appear to be moved to some random location.

To fix the issue, simply use the following line in viewDidLoad method;

```
self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

OR add the following line below `UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;` in `adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` method:-

```
piece.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Cheers!:-)